# MDAC and ActiveSync for Windows 7 64bit - need help

Tags: windows-7, activesync, mdac

i try to install my C# program on Windows 7 64bit and i got error.

i need to install MDAC  and  ActiveSync on computer.

from where i can download MDAC (that fit for Win-7 64 bit) and ActiveSync ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

MDAC and ActiveSync were replaced in Windows Vista (and Windows 7) with [Windows DAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692882(v=VS.85).aspx) and Windows Mobile Device Center.  Windows DAC (and Windows Mobile Device Center) is bundled with Windows Vista (and Windows 7), and shouldn't need reinstallation.

The [MDAC FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692877(VS.85).aspx) mentions that applications often use the wrong version of MSADO15.DLL; that might be your problem.

Alternatively, the problem might be that you're linking to 32-bit components from a platform-neutral application, which, on a 64-bit platform, is 64 bits.

If that's the case, you have two options:

1. Rebuild your application specifying 'x86' as the build type, instead of 'anycpu', or
2. Change the [executable flags](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,cf345d71-cdc7-46b9-8c1c-eb21581a9222.aspx) on your application to force 32-bit mode.